# Method remove() from LinkedList doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this simple Java exercise work, but it doesn't and I can't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
public LinkedList<T> toSet()
{
    LinkedList<T> retList; 
    retList = lista;
    for(T elem1 : retList)
        for(T elem2 :retList)
        {
            if(retList.indexOf(elem1) == retList.indexOf(elem2)) 
                continue;
            else if(elem1.equals(elem2)) 
                retList.remove(elem1);
        }

    return retList;
}
```

The method should remove the elements that appears more than one time in the list. I've debugged it with eclipse and I found that `retList.remove(elem1)` leaves the list unchanged!

Where is my mistake?

Comment: If this worked, it would throw a CommodificationException. Consider using iterators for your loops.

Comment: I suggest you use a Set.  This will ensure you don't have duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Do you mean a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `.clone()`

`LinkedList<T> retList = (LinkedList<T>) lista.clone();`

Also, you need to use iterators to remove from a `LinkedList` while in a loop. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2344096/195488).

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution is to use a Set.  In your case you can use.

```
public Set<T> toSet() {
   return new LinkedHashSet<T>(lista);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove items from a list while iterating over it with the for-each loop. You should use an iterator instead :

```
public LinkedList<T> toSet()
{
    LinkedList<T> retList; 
    retList = lista;
    Iterator<T> iter1 = retList.iterator();
    int index1 = 0;
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        T elem1 = iter1.next();
        Iterator<T> iter2 = retList.iterator();
        int index2 = 0;
        while (iter2.hasNext())
        {
            T elem2 = iter2.next();
            if(index1 != index2 && elem1.equals(elem2)) 
                iter2.remove();
            index2++;
        }
        index1++;
    }

    return retList;
}
```

Comment: I agree on using iterators, and removing only from the iterator's `remove`. However, as it stands, I think your `iter2` should be created *inside* the first `while`. Otherwise, on the second iteration of the outer loop, `iter2` won't `hasNext`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `retList` be a new list, and have `iter1` be an iterator from the original list? Won't removing an element from `iter2` cause `iter1` to throw an exception?

Comment: @afsantos You are right about `iter2`. Thanks! As for your second comment, I'm not sure whether it would throw an exception or not. I didn't create a new list because the OP didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You say that this is an exercise, and I'm assuming here that the goal is to produce a list representing a set (no duplicates), without using the `Set` collections.

Since it is an exercise, I won't provide full code, but I'll provide a different approach from other answers.

1. Create a new, empty, `Map<T, Object>`.
2. Create an object to serve as value, a simple `new Object()` will suffice.
3. Create a new, empty, `LinkedList<T>`. This is the list you will return.
4. Create an `Iterator<T>` from your list. This can be done with `lista.iterator()`.
5. Iterate over your list, while your iterator `hasNext()`:

   1. Retrieve current element, using your iterator's `next()`.
   2. Check if your map `containsKey()`, which is the element retrieved in 5.1.

      - If it does, the element is a duplicate, and you won't add it to the new list.
        Just skip.
      - If it doesn't, the element is fresh, so you `add()` it to the new list, and `put()` it in the map, as a key, pointing to the placeholder value created in 2.
   3. Repeat 5, ie, the loop continues.
6. Return the new list, which has no duplicates.