# Remove an element from the linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

How to remove an element from the linked list?

Is it correct way:

```
public E remove(E element) {
        Node search = currentNode;
        boolean nonStop = true;
        while(((search.previous) != null) && (nonStop)) {
            if(search.previous.toString().equals(element.toString())) {
                System.out.println("Item found !!!");
                search.previous = search.previous.previous;
                nonStop = false;
            } else {
                search = search.previous;
            }
        }
        currentNode = search;
        return null;
    }

public class Node<E> {
    public E data;
    public Node<E> previous;

    public Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void printNode() {
        System.out.println("Node details: "+data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (String)data;
    }

}
```

The problem is when I am printing all elements, getAllElements() is NOT giving correct answer,is there any problem in remove() method or getAllElements

```
public void getAllElements() {
        Node<E> aNode = currentNode;
        while(aNode != null) {
            aNode.printNode();
            aNode = aNode.previous;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the detail of your linked list? Is it single-linked or double-linked? Is it linear or circular?

Comment: Any reason you are not using one if the standard Lists in the runtime?

Comment: In case you want to review your code or want to improve your code post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Learn data structures

Comment: Have you tested it yourself? If so, does it work? If not, why not?

Comment: It is a singly linkedlist

Comment: What's a `Node`? It's impossible to tell whether this is correct without knowing how `Node` is defined. (It's probably not correct, since you're comparing elements by their `toString` representations, you seem to be missing the case where the element is the last item in the list, and if these `Node`s have a `next` as well as a `previous`, you're not updating that.)

Comment: Why compare their toString() value instead of comparing them with equals()? Why reimplement a LinkedList when a standard one already exists?

Comment: One thing that is certainly bad is `search.previous.toString().equals(element.toString())`.  You should use `equals` without using `toString` first.

Comment: I find it very strange that `Node` has a `previous` member instead of a `next` and that you called the head of your linked-list `currentNode` instead of, I don't know, `head`.

Comment: `(String)data` works pretty much only when `data` is a `String`. `data.toString()` would be preferred.

Comment: Can you give some sample input with expected and actual output showing that `getAllElements` gives the incorrect results? Also, preferably post a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/#selfcon).

Comment: So you are essentially trying to implement a data structure to learn how to do it?  (This is a very good thing).  In that case, you need to add information about your data structure data structure and how you want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if(search.previous.toString().equals(element.toString())
```

calls to string on the node and not on the element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your *remove method* does not really remove anything, you should update the pointers in your method so that nothing points toward the element you want to remove, and then garbage collector will the remove the element that nothing points to. Some pseudocode to illustrate what I mean:

```
public remove(Element element){
  for (Element e : myLinkedList){
    if (e.equals(element)){
      if (next != 0)
        previousPtr = nextPtr;
      else
        previousPtr = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is *not* correct Java code, just pseudocode to give you an idea, I save some fun for you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void remove(E element)
{
    Node n = head;  // This is the head of the linked list-- It is the starting node of your linked list: For your case "currentNode"
    Node tmp;
    while(n!=null && !n.data.equals(element))
    {
        tmp = n;
        n = n.previous;
    }

    if(n==null)
    {
        // Do your stuff
        System.out.println("Element "+element+" not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do your stuff
        tmp.prev = n.prev;
        n.prev = null;
        System.out.println("Element "+element+" removed.");
    }
}


// Suggestion: This method name should be "printList()"
public void getAllElements()
{
    Node n = head;      // In your case: "currentNode"
    while(n!=null)
    {
        n.printNode();
        n = n.previous;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't your elements have some kind of identifier?
Then you can do it much simpler, like here: [remove an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343620/linkedlist-remove-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

```
public E remove(E element) {
        Node search = currentNode;
        boolean nonStop = true;
        while(((search.previous) != null) && (nonStop)) {
            if(search.previous.data.equals(element)) {
                System.out.println("Item found !!!");
                search.previous = search.previous.previous;
                nonStop = false;
            }
            search = search.previous;
        }
       return null;
    }
```

I have found the solution for that Issue, thanks everyone for yours kind support.